# Status Information: 127, plugin may not be installed

Tags: python, nagios

So, the title pretty much says it. I'm trying to customize several plugins for nagios and several of them have to be in python.
I'm running Centos 6.5, Python 2.6.6, and Nagios Core 3.5.1

I've installed nagios and python use the yum repository, and everything works when run from the command line, even as the nagios user. I can get bash scripts to run from the nagios system just fine, but even trying to wrap the python in a bash script doesn't work. Whatever I run, even something as simple as

```
echo `/usr/bin/python --version`
```

returns an empty or null string.

It also apparently exits with status zero (even when the run code should have produced something else) no matter what I do. This problem appears to be specific to Python and not have anything to do with basic permissions. It might have something to do with ACLs, though I have no idea what. Does anyone have any ideas for what might be going wrong?

Comment: type `whereis python` into your bash shell, what do you get? i can't speak for 2.6.6 but for 2.7 on linux at my personal pc, python defaults to `/usr/bin/python2.7` so you may just be missing a part of the path

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi As with most python installations, /usr/bin/python2.6 exists but so does /usr/bin/python. This is not an issue with the script, python itself, or the arguments. I've tested all of that to death. It's something about the way nagios runs things.

Comment: Could be, sorry I can't be of much use with Nagios, but I will be following this as I'm trying to convert work to Nagios and we have a heavy use of python :)

Comment: What does 'fails to run' mean? What error do you get (logs etc.)?

Comment: @Shaman Are you sure the environment that Nagios is running under is correct? i.e. your `PATH`, etc

Comment: @simurg That's the problem. It doesn't error. It just plain fails to run, outputs nothing, and (apparently) exits with status code 0. As though /usr/bin/python had been replaced with a script that just runs an empty echo statement.

Comment: @PatrickCollins Bash scripts in the exact location with the exact permissions work so its not that. I've run the script as the Nagios user so I don't THINK its anything to do with that. But I don't know how Nagios runs its scripts, so I don't what else to check.

Comment: @Shaman Wouldn't `echo \`..\`` return 0 and exit if the code inside the backticks failed?

Comment: @PatrickCollins Now that mention it, possibly, if the stacktrace was sent to stderr instead of stdout. However, how exactly does one cause `python --version` to fail in one and only one environment? (Also the status 0 happens whether I'm echoing or not.)

Comment: @Shaman Can't say. But I think `/usr/bin/python --version` should be enough to test it, right? Because that will do the printing to `stdout` for you, you don't need to `echo` it, and then you can see the real status code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73222/discussion-between-shaman-and-patrick-collins).

Comment: change your echo to `echo \`/usr/bin/python -V 2>&1\`` to capture stderr; also note `-V` instead of `--version`

Comment: @qarma Thanks. I literally tried that 2 minutes ago and it finally got me some out, so I tried it with my other code and it turns out all the python modules were installed with root only access

Comment: Now, I still have no idea why NONE of my tests work... but at least I've got something to work with. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nagios can display some really odd behaviors when things exit with an unknown status and no output. It turns out that a good first debugging step is to try adding something like

```
<command> 2>&1
```

or

```
echo `<command> 2>&1`
```

to your plugin call to check what stderr is telling you.